# SegmentationFault linux AFS

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

Can someone tell me how to debug segmentation fault in linux VIA AFS. I would appreciate if someone could refer me  command. I am able to run my code via compiler but not on when i give command g++ -o file1 file2.cpp----> ./file----->segmentation fault

Comment: Try to improve the ouput debugging info with this:
g++ -o file1 file2.cpp -g -Wall

Comment: Compile with full debugging symbols. Also look into valgrind.

Comment: Are you looking for a single command to magically "debug segmentation fault"? It doesn't exist. You need to learn the art of debugging, and that's way out of scope of a Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile the program with the `-g` option

```
g++ -g -o file1 file2.cpp
```

Then execute the executable created with gdb.

```
gdb file1
```

Once you see the seg fault issue `bt`, this will give you the stack.
`frame <frame number>` you can see the details about the particular stack. 
Happy debugging.